# Spring Batch - XML to DB - how to always fresh data (whatever present in XML file) for multiple runs?

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am developing `Spring Batch - XML to DB example`. In this example, I want to load XML data into DB. Per current implementation, if I run the main program then XML data is getting loaded into DB successfully, again I run the main program again data is getting loaded into DB (with previous runs output - for second run, it's all duplicates). What if I don't want to persist old data i.e., whenever I run the main code I should get fresh data (whatever present into DB) into table. What configuration do I need to change in DB ?

**spring-batch-context.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:context-datasource.xml"/>
    <!-- ============= ItemReader which reads data from XML file ============= -->
    <bean id="xmlItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:examResult.xml" />
        <property name="fragmentRootElementName" value="ExamResult" />
        <property name="unmarshaller">
            <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                <property name="classesToBeBound">
                    <list>
                        <value>com.websystique.springbatch.model.ExamResult</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- ================ ItemWriter which writes data to database ================= -->
    <bean id="databaseItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[        
                    insert into EXAM_RESULT(STUDENT_NAME, DOB, PERCENTAGE) values (?, ?, ?)
                ]]>
            </value>
        </property>
        <!-- We need a custom setter to handle the conversion between Jodatime LocalDate and MySQL DATE -->
        <property name="ItemPreparedStatementSetter">
            <bean class="com.websystique.springbatch.ExamResultItemPreparedStatementSetter" />
        </property>
  </bean>
    <!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input records -->
    <bean id="itemProcessor" class="com.websystique.springbatch.processor.ExamResultItemProcessor" />
    <!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and after the job -->
    <bean id="jobListener" class="com.websystique.springbatch.utils.ExamResultJobListener" />
    <!-- ==================== Actual Job ========================= -->
    <batch:job id="examResultJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="xmlItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter" processor="itemProcessor" commit-interval="10" />
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:listeners>
            <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
        </batch:listeners>
    </batch:job>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to fulfill your requirement you only need to change the query.

You should make your student name a primary key in your table and
then change the query in configuration file.

```
"insert into EXAM_RESULT(STUDENT_NAME, DOB, PERCENTAGE) 
values (?, ?, ?) on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DOB = ? ,PERCENTAGE=?"
```

Supply the values to positional parameters in 
`ExamResultItemPreparedStatementSetter`.

Hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Add a new tasklet as first step to delete data from table just before import.
You can achive it using [Tasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/Tasklet.html)

```
public class SQLStmtTasklet implements Tasklet{
  private DataSource dataSource;
  private String sql;

  public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
    //  Execute your sql statement
    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;       
  }
}
```

This is a skeleton of a Takslet; just add accessors and fille the `execute()` method.